# calling delete on the shallow copy not blow up

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

In the below code, memory is allocated for an integer and later a shallow copy is being made and finally delete is being called on it. How does it still print 23 as the output and why doesn't the delete call on q, cause a run time exception.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* p = new int(23);
    int* q = p;

    delete p;
    cout << *p << endl;
    delete q;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.

It might crash.

It might crash your car.

It might crash your brain.

It might crash Sagittarius A* into your brain.

It might crash your brain into your car, then crash them both into Sagittarius A*.

It might appear to work.

But it's still undefined.

Don't expect results.

Comment: @melpomene: Dammit 

Comment: Can it be so undefined, that it changes the standard to become defined?

Comment: @George ... Dammit! 

Comment: @George: To be fair, by the as-if rule, combined with the notion that the code could "appear to work", I suppose the answer is yes.

Comment: @George but why does delete q work
Should not the memory be marked as unavailable and further call to delete cause a runtime error. 

Does calling delete again on the same memory location just mark it as unavailable again or is the behavior still undefined

Comment: @Tousif Your assumption that there should be a runtime error has been invented. Who told you that there must be a runtime error? They may not be a runtime error. It's chance. It's undefined. It depends on the implementation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am just trying to wrap my head around the concept of memory deallocation. Your comment is really appreciated.

Comment: @Tousif I think the key point you may be missing is that memory "availability" is not checked on every access by the runtime - this would be an unacceptable performance hit. But from the C++ standards POV it _could be_ - it's undefined!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks a lot. So, to be safe the delete q should not be called.

Comment: @Tousif Absolutely. A double-delete is a serious bug. Ideally you wouldn't be doing manual memory management at all...

Comment: @Tousif to be safe you shouldnt have used `new` in the first place

Comment: @user463035818 it was a toy example to clarify my doubt.